# Estou com uma div que não esta funcionando

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, div

Tem 2 `Div` com o parâmetro `Container` o problema é que a segunda está funcionando e aplicando normalmente o `CSS`, mas a primeira não funciona. Já mudei de Lugar o fechamento mas não adiantou. Alguém sabe o que é?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Site Vilgger</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/jquery.js.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

                <div calss="container">

                    <div calss="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navegacao">
                             <span class="sr-only">Mostrar / Ocultar </span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                        </button>

                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Site Vilgger</a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacao">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#"> Inicio</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                    Categorias
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                                </ul>     
                            </li>

                            <li> <a href="#">Blog </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Contato </a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="from-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>    
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>

        </header>

        <section class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1> Blog WEB</h1>
                <p>Blog Web Design </p>

            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="main container"> </section>

        <section class=""></section>

        <footer></footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brother, você tá escrevendo a palavra `class` errado.

Dá uma olha aqui: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwgk82sh/1/)

Eu usei o seu código, então, pode copiar e colar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.c">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Site Vilgger</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navegacao">
                            <span class="sr-only">Mostrar / Ocultar </span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Site Vilgger</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacao">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Inicio</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                    Categorias <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                                </ul>     
                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Blog </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Contato </a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="from-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>    
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1> Blog WEB</h1>
                <p>Blog Web Design </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="main container"> </section>
        <section class=""></section>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```